# how to change this/context in setTimeout when anonymous function is passed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a click event for a element. I am executing code after a delay. So i am using settimeout inside click event.

My html :

```
<button id="button">CLICK ME</button>
```

My js :

```
jQuery('#button').on('click',function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(this);
  },50)
});
```

I want to change `this` inside `setTimeout` function.
One solution i know is to create a named function and then using bind.

```
   var test = function(){
        console.log(this);
    }
    jQuery('#button').on('click', function () {
      setTimeout(test.bind(this),10);

    });
```

I don't want to use named function everytime. 
So how can i bind `this` with anonymous function?
Here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/gautam/pen/myJpgo) to work with.

Comment: Do you want [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwpZOg)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to to use a named function.

```
jQuery('#button').on('click', function () {
    setTimeout((function(){
        console.log(this);
    }).bind(this),10);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply save it into another variable that is scoped outside the setTimeout.

```js
jQuery('#button').on('click',function(){
  var $this = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log($this);
  },50)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I know I can do like that, but i need to change `this`.

Comment: I don't follow - `$this` will always have its newest form when the button is clicked. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I understood, problem is users will add code inside timeout function. So i want change the context such that a user can do `btn = $(this);`

Answer (score 1):

You can `.bind()` with anonymous function also.

```js
jQuery('#button').on('click',function(){
  setTimeout((function(){
    console.log(this);
  }).bind(this),50)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```